# How do I do sql query on access by ignoring one column

Tags: ms-access

How do I filter the query using only one column and regardless of what other column has same field or different field in sql ms-access.

```
TABLE
person    product    sales

A         Z          100
B         R          100
A         R          200
A         X          500
```

I would like to result to be:

```
person   product    sales    total_sales
A        Z          100        800
A        R          200        800
A        X          500        800
B        R          100        100
```

Thank You

Comment: Your question is not clear, please try to explain exactly what your problem is or post some of the sql that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you can use a sub-query to get the results you want for the total_sales field.

```
SELECT person, product, sales, (
    SELECT SUM(sales) AS sum_of_sales
    FROM sales_table sub_sales
    WHERE sub_sales.person = main_person.person
) AS total_sales
FROM person_table main_person
JOIN product_table main_product
JOIN sales_table main_sales
```

Just pseudo-code, you'll need to create the proper joins of course.